# Invoking Nagios in-built plugins

Tags: java, plugins, integration, nagios

My system admin has installed Nagios on Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS. How should I go about invoking Nagios in-built Plugins for example check_disk from shell.

Answer (score 0):

Move to the folder where your plugins are in

cd /usr/local/nagios/libexec

./check_disk --options

for example:

./check_disk -w 80% -c 90% -M

Comment: I am able do the same, played with other commands, worked well. As an extension to this question, where does NRPE stand? It it a proxy or a daemon process? How do we invoke it? When I run check_nrpe command it returns version of NRPE like 2.12.